# Opencv custom shape detection

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I want to find a specific line and it's starting and ending (x,y) coordinates Using opencv in android studio.
I tried Hough Line Transform but I failed.

[image]

In the above picture, I added a green circle on the line I want to find.
This line can be anywhere in the picture but always close to the white circle and also height of the line can be different.

Please help me if someone knows a solution to my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Muhammad! I think it would be helpful for another users if you share what have you tried to achieve this, I mean a snippet of the code you're writing.

Comment: I just convert the image into grayscale and applied the threshold.

Comment: But, how you do it? What are you tried to detect the line you want to detect? If you have not developed nothing to address your issue, perhaps you need to read some OpenCV [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html) and its [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/). Then it would be easier to help with your exact issue if you would have problems developing what you want.